# How to run test cases of php-activerecords

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I am working on a fix of [php-activerecords](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord) and want to make sure that my fix does not break the build. I want to run already written test cases but have to idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml test/
```

Take a look at the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/.travis.yml) file for the other things to be set up (database connections mostly).